# How do I detect contiguous sublists with values above a certain threshold?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have very basic programming skills. My question is how to detect contiguous sublists of a given list, such that all members of the sublist are above a certain threshold. There may be more than one such sublist in the list. For instance, we have a list called list1 as below:

```
list1 =  [5, 10, 9, 11, 22, 19, 23, 2, 2, -1, 1, 4, 5, 19, 20, 40, 32, 34, 7, 3, -2, 4, 5 , 7 , 22, 23, 24, 35]
```

I want to be able to detect sublists that are above 18 and retrieve the lowest value within that sublist returning its index. There are 3 such sublists in `list1`: `[22, 19, 23]`, `[19, 20, 40, 32, 34]`, and `[22, 23, 24, 25]`. Therefore the result I am looking for is `[5, 13, 24]`, the indices of the minimum value in each sublist. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "pattern"? Can you give an example of what result you would want to be returned from this list?

Comment: For example: the values in the  pattern it detects is 22,19,23 which are above the threshold value 18 and finds the minimum in it which is 19 and return its index and again it loops through the list, picks the next pattern which is 19, 20, 40, 32, 34  and returns the lowest value's index. makes sense?

Comment: I made an edit to attempt to clarify the question a bit more. Please check it for accuracy.

Comment: thank you for clarifying the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided I understand what you're looking for correctly, this should do the trick.  The idea is to go through our list and make smaller lists(`templist`) of the numbers greater than 18, then once we find a number that is not greater than 18 we know we are done adding to this sublist and can check for the minimum, and get its index.  I'm just printing things out but you can easily save the info with a few small changes.

```
list1 = [5, 10, 9, 11, 22, 19, 23, 2, 2, -1, 1, 4, 5, 19, 20, 40, 32, 34, 7, 3, -2, 4, 5 , 7 , 22, 23, 24, 35]
templist = []
for i,l in enumerate(list1):
    if(l > 18):
        templist.append(l)
    else:
        if len(templist) > 0:
            print(i-len(templist)+templist.index(min(templist)),min(templist))
            templist = []
if len(templist) > 0:
    print(i-len(templist)+templist.index(min(templist)),min(templist))
    templist = []
```

Comment: brilliant - worked thank you heaps. But i will need to learn about enumerate. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would iterate though and temporarily store the value as well as the index of the values matching your pattern as long as you find a value which doesn't match the pattern.
Then you need to find the smallest number and store it's index value
Clear your temporary pattern storage and keep on iterating until you reach the end

Quick and dirty this may look like this in python:

```
def get_min_indx(data):
    emin = data[0]
    for e in data:
        # check values
        if e[1] < emin[1]: emin = e
    return emin[0]

def find_pattern(data,pattern_threshold):
    pattern_found = []
    indxs = []

    for idx,e in enumerate(data):
        if e > pattern_threshold:
            # found an element: store it's index and it's value
            pattern_found.append((idx,e))
        elif len(pattern_found) != 0:
            indxs.append(get_min_indx(pattern_found))    
            # reset our pattern_storage
            pattern_found = []
    if len(pattern_found) != 0:
        indxs.append(get_min_indx(pattern_found))
    return indxs


list1 = [5, 10, 9, 11, 22, 19, 23, 2, 2, -1, 1, 4, 5, 19, 20, 40, 32, 34, 7, 3, -2, 4, 5 , 7 , 22, 23, 24, 35]
pattern_threshold = 18

print(find_pattern(list1,pattern_threshold))
```

Comment: thank you heaps. :)  But i will need to learn about enumerate.

Comment: of course again thank you for your help and quick response. its such a great platform to learn so quick.